# Dynamic SQL on DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

I have to get a dynamically created SQL-Query to work with a DataSet. I'm using a DataSet where I store some information from the database file (MS-Access).

Now I want the user to be able to select special filters - and depending on them I create a SQL-Query, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x <> 0 AND y >= 10
```

The problem is, that the parameters are completely dynamic, so it could as well look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x <= 50 AND y IN (10, 50, 43)
```

So I can't use a TableAdapter for it. How yould I get this working?

I already came across the `Select()`-function of a Table adapter where I can define `filter expression` but I'm not quite sure how they should look like. Any help there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two links. Might help you -

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/4294d5bf-ae82-4326-9cf2-35f413cd7783

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/24479/how-to-filter-dataset.aspx